# Adding Runtime Property in Object doesn't show in "this" context

Tags: javascript, typescript, defineproperty

Just wondering , why when `this` is printed on console , doesn't show the dynamic `property`, which is added using `Object.defineProperty`

Here is a [Decorator example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAZgliwBMDOAuCSwCcYDsDmA2gLoQC8ExA3ALABQokAxjpOQAw211QCuOjYGAHscETCACOPGOIQAKMAENMecGkU4AngBoIABxxoM2fAEoIAbzoRocREgB0enkgAWcg6c4BfOn9q8-IIiEABuisAwCIpgIArKqmDqWroGyToQCCCoEBqapumW-jbiYDyYola0NjaJcuZVNTWw8MgOALaKenJyLYhGWLh45qQAfEXVTTUAhNNgrjBIBH0IJABkaxDMYADUO5xTEN5e1lOMIkhCoA6MoMr1B2cXkADumF16IJgAYqLkcg5AQkcnliCNxo1Dplsg5wsAeCAHB9gJoFAskLpgaZTk1fJMmuccBgIIsAKKYTBCTADEx4MhbFhkUjkFaOUD4eYQAD8EAA5EgeIxGNkkLyIGheV9KZheY8mgB5ABGACsQAIHFlYDgQAAFSmfTBgVHzRa6MkUqm6SGHOEItDm6XaHFPHCwPDlRSK0BoLAIp34qZvGBKL0gH2YBHOmzHOU1UrlURvD5fX6x7z+6N0PH+W6KJBICA6r6XSrFCAAAXEUhkIAQp1gmAwOEU7TD6EG+E4p0rkmkslOwDzYGbrZpQy7kyySEY2D0wUM7dpE5sPer-cmqhwWWpi-HZcJxkFYCpvRHbeMQ10wDPY-wuinM5gc+EC4vd-QIAAHrfhhMmibHAbJsWxAekoDPWMAIcQdgNbelrxAyD0Q1bJH2fEJyAfWd5yQxYHE3bd6SQL9HmzLhJnLOEohiEBTmcL0YEYMIImo2Jvipdp6jQUIhCiP8agPK5EWAIQ8DRRYTgDGAoAgOR+UFYV8zFXAIAAhooy2C4hOg0S5KgDiSQLAUhRFXhgF5bEA28CB4GIkkZLkqUqWU0Q1P4gktOuESxMlC1MBJUR9MwdoLLTU48TIhh9GLDCIG1F5CxinA5IAVRwABrHAhBeURvhkYkz15XReTSzLstEAAZIc4pAoqACI6uKgBZUK6ANEtYRY6I2I4h5-CAA). It's working as expected but the `success`, `error` property is not shown in `this`. I guess this is `javascript` behaviour and has nothing to do with decorators.

May I get a glimpse of this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Try to assign true to 'enumerable' property of property descriptor object.